# Perform operations directly on database (esp. Firestore)

Tags: database, google-cloud-firestore

Just a question regarding NoSQL DB. As far as I know, operations are done by the app/website outside the DB. For instance, if I need to add an value to a list, I need to

1. download the intial list
2. add the new value in the list on my device
3. upload the whole updated list.

At the end, a lot of data is travelling (twice the initial list) with no added value.

Is there any way to request directly the DB for simple operations like this?

```
db.collection("collection_key").document("document_key").add("mylist", value)
```

Or simply increment a field?

Same for knowing the number of documents in a collection: is it needed to download the whole set of document to get the number ?

Comment: Please edit the question to be more clear about the data you want to modify, showing the code you have now that doesn't work the way you expect. Giving a specific example will help.  On Stack Overflow, you should also limit yourself to a single question per post, or the question could get closed as "needing focus".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple different answers:

In Firestore, many intrinsic operations can be done "FieldValues", such as increment/decrement (by supplied value, so really Add/subtract).  Also array unions, field deletes, etc.  Just search the documentation for FieldValue.  Whether this is true for NoSQL in general, I can't say.

Knowing the number of documents, on the other hand. is not trivially done in Firestore - but frankly, I can't think of any situations other than artificially contrived examples where you would *need* to know.  Easy enough to setup ways to "count" documents as you create/delete them, and keep that separately, if for some reason you find yourself needing it.

Or were you just trying to generically put down NoSQL as a concept?

Comment: In fact, I manage data in a list, in order to effectively avoid downloading all the documents in the sub-collection. So I try to add a label in the list for each added document, and I want to avoid unnecessary back and forth.

Otherwise in general I just try to make others work more than me :) in this case the servers around the DB to avoid unnecessary data flows. I look at FieldValue which must answer the question.